# Image Drop Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented a cancel button which clears taken image and assign it to the nil. However I would like to implement an animation when user clicks on the cancel button, the taken image drops and goes out of the screen.

How could I able to achieve it?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    selectPhotoBtnOutlet.hidden=YES;
    takePhotoBtnOutlet.hidden=YES;
    __block PhotosViewController *aBlockSelf = self; 
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        aBlockSelf.productImg.hidden = NO;
        aBlockSelf.makeTF.hidden = NO;
        aBlockSelf.cancelBtnOutlet.hidden=NO;
        aBlockSelf.productImg.image = chosenImage;
    }];
 }


- (IBAction)cnclBtnClick:(id)sender {
    self.productImg.image = nil;
    self.cancelBtnOutlet.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: Instead of a "sample", how about doing some programming? Animation is easy on iOS. Why not learn how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this `animateWithDuration` completion block to remove the view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{
                     [self.productImg setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.productImg.frame.size.width, self.productImg.frame.size.height)]; //this is moving the y of the self.productImg down
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [self.productImg removeFromSuperview];
                     self.productImg.image = nil;
                     self.cancelBtnOutlet.hidden=YES;
                 }];
```